# link multiple database models in django by unrelated fields

Tags: django, django-models

In sql if there are two table which have fields that have data with resemblance but do not have connection together you can links them up like this

```
select tab1.name,  tab1.gender,  tab1.occupation, tab2.location , tab2.biz_time ,tab3.address 
from staffdata tab1, sales tab2, address tab3 where 
tab1.user_id=tab2.user_id and tab3.location_id=tab2.location_id
```

this would link them up to produce results from the 3 tables I have tried subquery,
annotate with values but was getting wrong result

this is what i have tried

```
code_subquery = SalesRecord.objects.filter(staff__username__iexact=request.user,
                            user_id=OuterRef('user_id'))


timetablevalues= StaffData.objects.filter(staff=request.user,
        user_id=Subquery( code_subquery.values(
            'location', 'biz_time', 'item')))\
        .values('name','gender',
        'location', 'biz_time', 'item')
```

Although this is for 2 tables but I might do that of 3 tables later on

Please how can I go about it

Comment: Making arbitrary joins with Django ORM is not very easy and would require diving deep into the code. You should simply use raw queries if you want to do such things.

Comment: but would that not expose the code to sql injecttion? Sorry for the delay in reply

Comment: Not unless one passes parameters by string concatenation, etc. See [Passing parameters into raw()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw). In general raw queries are as insecure as the developer makes them. The ORM is more secure because it escapes values properly and uses parameterized queries etc. generally the secure practices when it translates the ORM query to SQL query.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat how can i make the query very secure in comparison with ORM?